# I set up a password for my phpmyadmin but now i cant enter

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, root

I used to enter my database if i type `localhost/phpmyadmin` to browser. But now i cant, because of i set up  a new password for `root@localhost` . I know what is the password but what should i type the browser's bar?

**note:**

1. Using [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/tr/index.html)
2. this s error note: ***#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)***

Comment: Should be a config file for it in phpmyadmin folder in xampp.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your config to expect a password. See more here: http://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/error-1045-phpmyadmin/.